# Plugin ribbon control button not showing the image

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have created a plugin button for the outlook in Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose.My problem is i can see the button but not the image.i am returning a bitmap image in the callback method.i also tried to convert the image using stdole.IPictureDisp,but no hope.Can anyone please tell me what i have missed.Should i try to add the image to the clipboard of the outlook?

Answer (score 0):

this code may help : https://github.com/frankfralick/InventorAddIns/blob/master/SimpleAddInIronPython/PictureDispConverter.cs

Call ToIPictureDisp to get stdole.IPictureDisp

Comment: I have tried the way u have said.but still no luck.please see the image.I have the ribbon buttons coming,but cannot find the image!i have buttons on the ribbon control but no image.